# Edit/Set value "Not Configured" for all folders and Keys under "Internet Explorer" GPO object (Local Computer Policy)

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer-11, group-policy, gpo

Is there any powershell command or script that can edit all folders, all keys under Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Internet Explorer
And set it to "Not Configured"?

Comment: There is command ` Set-ItemProperty ` . What's the path of your GPO

Comment: I want to edit it for every item under Internet Explorer

Comment: Path is "Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Internet Explorer"

Comment: I want a bulk itemProperty edit. Is this possible?

Comment: I searched a lot and didn't find a way to set all policies for IE using a command. I think you can only set them one by one using PowerShell commands. You can't set all the policies at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your time.. appreciate your help.